# why fbo can't generate right size of texture on macOS?

Tags: qt, opengl, fbo, opengl-4

I want to implement a function on my macOS, with QT.

I have a surface,
writes the result to a texture buffer instead of visualizing it
Then render it in fragment shader.
The size of the result is wrong.

limitFramebuffer is my QOpenGLFramebufferObject.

```
 // Render limit surface to framebuffer
        limitFramebuffer->bind();
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderers["Limit"]->render();
        limitFramebuffer->release();

        // Set limit framebuffer as current texture
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, limitFramebuffer->texture());
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

        QImage image0 = limitFramebuffer->toImage(); 
        QDateTime d = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        QString date = d.toString("dd.MM.yyyy.hh:mm:ss.zzz") + ".png";
        QString fileName =  "./../../../../MeshTool/examples/texture/" + date;
```

The image saved is
[image]

It shoulde be:
[image]

As we can see, the texture generated contains only a quarter of the original image from the bottom left corner.

I use
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, limitFramebuffer->texture());
to bind the texture.

How can I make the texture contain all the data in the FBO?
Why does the FBO contain only a quarter of the data?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you adjust the viewport rectangle to the size of the framebuffer?

Comment: @Rabbid76 No, can I ask how to do that?

Comment: The OpenGL command is [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml). You must adjust the size of the viewport to the size of the bound frame buffer.